# Get and keep only original target of mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want to get and keep only the original target element of a `mousedown` event -- but as the user holds the mouse down, the `event.target` changes depending on what's under the pointer.

There is a property `event.originalTarget` which does exactly what I want, but it's only supported by Firefox (reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget ).

How can I replicate this behavior using standard `event.target`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: you need to create flags outside the event listener.

```
let el = false
let mousedown = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', ev => {
        if (!mousedown) {
            el = ev.target;
            mousedown = true;
        }
    });

document.addEventListener('mouseup', ev => {
        mousedown = false;
        el = false;
    });
```

So `el` will be set as the original target for the duration of the `mousedown`, but on `mouseup`, it's reset back to nothing.

Comment: `this` (in your specific case) and [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) are referring to the element the event was attached as well, no flags needed.

Comment: @Teemu Interesting -- was not aware of that!

Comment: Ah, there's a typo in my comment, should have been "_not in your specific case_" because of the arrow function.

Comment: The flag-based version ended up being useful anyway, to coordinate other behaviors based on original target and mouse state.